WP_Query on custom taxonomy -> Location and Activity
A store location site displays stores based on region, town OR activity.
I am using the WP Store Locator plugin and also using Divi Builder to create the pages.
This is proving quite powerful and I can create pages displaying a map with markers and a list of post entries for either a region, a town or an activity (like Cafes).
It's proving difficult to create pages that selects a town and a specific activity. For instance, if I want to display all cafes in the town Timbuktu I cannot seem to do this.
I believe I will need to create some custom functions or code to achieve this
The field I wish to reference is "tax_input[wpsl_store_category][]" where this array can have multiple values based on the categories and sub-categories I have added to it, like Town > Timbuktu and Activity > Cafe.
So, if I create a page, somthing like https://xyz.com/timbuktu/timbuktu-cafes/ how would I create a query and / or a shortcode to get the necessary data from the database and present it to the page template?
Here is a page example that shows a) a map (I wont need the map - it is created via a WP Store Locator shortcode) and b) all the entries for a specific town. I wish to limit this to specific activities e.g. cafes: https://greatroadtrip.au/town/healesville/
